# Android Access RadioButton in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've just created an `ExpandableListView` with a custom adapter. The child layout of the list view have a `TextView` and a `RadioGroup` (with 2 `RadioButton`). 
For example, my list will have:

- Connections group

  - Bluetooth: on off
  - WIFI: on off

I was able to populate the list (insert bluetooth and wifi) but I don't understand how to access the value of each `RadioGroup`.

Bluetooth and wifi children are created by the adapter with the child layout. How can get the value of bluetooth and the value of wifi?
How can I use `findViewById` method if I have many children of the `ExpandableList`, each one with the same id?
NB: I need to retrive the radioButtons's value all at once when I press a save button.

Thank you,

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the selected item, you can set on onClickListener to the view variable

Comment: ok, that work if I must retrive the value when the user select it but how can I get all he values from all radiobutton when I press a "save" button?